# Using subprocess.run to run a process on Windows

Tags: python, subprocess, windows-shell

I wish to run the following very lengthy shell command via Python:

```
C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe "E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat" pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition
```

When I run this as-is from the Windows shell, it works as expected.

However, when I attempt to do the same via Python's `subprocess.run`, it doesn't like it. Here is my input:

```
import subprocess
comm = [r'C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe "E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat" pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition']
subprocess.run(comm, shell=True)
```

Here is my output:

```
The directory name is invalid.
Out[5]: CompletedProcess(args=['C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe "E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat" pc\\ndf\\patchable\\gfx\\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition'], returncode=1)
```

Why does this occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spacing is wrong.  subprocess is expecting a list of arguments which it will space out correctly for you.

```
comm = ['C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe','E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat','pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin','TAmmunition']
```

The reason you are getting the error is because of the doublequotes around e:/steam... 
It's writing something like this to a shell:

```
c:/users/alex/desktop/tableexporter/wgtableexporter.exe \"E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat\" pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition
```

Answer (score 1):

The spacing is incorrect, however using `os.system()` will not require you to change spacing.

This should work:

```
import os
os.system("""C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe      "E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat" pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition""")
```

However if you want to use subprocess (which is better)

```
import subprocess
comm = ['C:/Users/Alex/Desktop/tableexporter/WGTableExporter.exe','E:/Steam (Games Installed Directly to Hard Drive)/steamapps/common/Wargame Red Dragon/Data/WARGAME/PC/430000626/NDF_Win.dat','pc\ndf\patchable\gfx\everything.ndfbin TAmmunition']
subprocess.run(comm, shell=True)
```