# How would I Launch utorrent.exe (on disk) with python

Tags: python, windows

I can't seem to figure out how to launch a program on Windows (utorrent.exe) with python

I am not sure how to go about it

any advice would be appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['<path-to-executable>/utorrent.exe'])
```

Refer to the [subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492351/using-subprocess-run-to-run-a-process-on-windows).

Comment: Use `shell=False` here. There is no need to run an executable via cmd.exe.

Comment: Also, using the shell prevents `run` from killing the utorrent process in case we decide to include a timeout. It will kill the shell and leak utorrent as an orphan.